# How to create a horizontal WebSphere 7 cluster

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I have a WebLogic and Tomcat background and, when our group lost the WebSphere admin, became the natural person to take over WebSphere. My first real task is to take the two existing WebSphere installations and cluster 1 application between them.

Both installations have a single cell with 2 nodes. 1 node on each is for the deployment manager and the other node contains all the servers on the installation (1 server per application). I, apparently, cannot simply add a node or server from one installation to a cluster on the other, because the nodes and servers are already tied to that installation's (cell's?) deployment manager.

The logical step, to me, would be to create a node without a deployment manager. If I follow the instructions to create an unmanaged node (makes sense, right?), I cannot add a server (existing or new) to it.

Please help.

Comment: Do you want to completely combine the two Cells, or just one application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To cluster Servers, they must be running on Nodes which are "federated" into the same Cell. 
If you're interested in having all applications belong to a single Cell, you can use [`removeNode`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_removenode.html) and [`addNode`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rxml_addnode.html) to move one of the Nodes over to the other Cell.

If, instead, you want to have some applications/servers on a machine belong to one Cell and others to another, I'm thinking you may need to create an additional WebSphere profile so that you can have multiple NodeAgents running on different ports on the same machine. But I'm not positive about this approach. I guess I'd encourage having a single Cell, but I don't know what cases you're addressing by having multiple Cells currently.

Comment: They are technically separate development and test servers, but we just don't have the hardware to install more WebSphere applications on other servers at this time and testing the clustered application across separate hardware is a must.

So the test and development servers each have 5 applications, 4 of which need to remain separate from each other and the 1 needs to be clustered across both.

My concern about using removeNode/addNode on one installation is that then we would only have one deployment manager for both environments, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thanks for clarifying the situation. I agree it makes sense to keep development & test Cells separate. It seems, then, that you need multiple Nodes on the same "server", in which case I *think* you have to create an additional profile.

Comment: Problem solved thanks to dbreaux!

1.) Create profile on server 2 using managed profileTemplate. This created node02 without a DM
2.) Federate node02 to server 1 using addNode under new profile
3.) Create cluster with servers on node01 (server 1) and node02 (server 2).

Sorry I have no reputation to vote up the answer, but if dbreaux ever finds him-/herself in central Virginia, I'll happily buy him/her dinner.